# Twilio Error as Could not load type 'Twilio.TwilioClient' from assembly 'Twilio, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

Tags: twilio

Here i'm using Visualstudio2013 update4 version when i run my project i'm getting error as  Could not load type 'Twilio.TwilioClient' from assembly 'Twilio, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

```
public ActionResult sendSms()
        {
            var accountSid = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["twilioaccountSid"];
            var authTokeon = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["authtoken"];
            TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authTokeon);
            var to= new PhoneNumber(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyPhoneNumber"]);
            var from = new PhoneNumber("");
            var msg = MessageResource.Create(
                to: to,
                from: from,
                body: "Hello Ghouse");
            return Content(msg.Sid);
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had this problem just yesterday. I had to google the error message taking out twilio "could not load type from assembly". It turns out that if I name my project twilio, that caused an error. So, I just rename my project something else, not using twilio anywhere in the name, and then everything worked fine. Also, be sure to install all the twilio packages from nuget. I hope this helps